# Low-pass filter + HRTF cascade audio artifacts

Tags: filters, audio-processing, real-time, hrtf

I am implementing a 3D audio application. I have correctly implemented a set of HRTF to perform binaural simulation and interpolation.

To achieve this, I converted the HRTF into minimum-phase ones, then I interpolated their IR and finally I added a ITD to the lagging ear (this is a common approach I found in many papers such as [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236169325_Creating_Interactive_Virtual_Acoustic_Environments))

The auralization and audio source movement works fine, I have implemented an Overlap-Add schema to avoid audible artifacts when changing the HRTF between audio frames.

I also tested a simple low-pass filter (using Scipy `lfilter`) with changing parameters, saving the filter state I have been able to change the filter parameters between audio frames without any audible artifact:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as ss

#Initialization inside my class
self.filter_state = np.zeros(4)

#function called to update the filter
def bandPassFilter(self,signal, highcut):
    fs = 44100
    lowcut = 20
    highcut = highcut

    nyq= 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq

    order = 2

    b, a = ss.butter(order, [low,high], 'bandpass', analog=False)

    y, self.filter_state = ss.lfilter(b,a,signal, axis=0, zi=self.filter_state) # NB: filtfilt needs forward and backward information to filter. So it can't be used in realtime filtering where i have no info about future samples! lfilter is better for real time applications!
    return(y)
```

However if I cascade the two filters (low-pass filter and HRTF) like in the following schema:

[image: schema]

I get again "clicking" artifacts between changes in the filters. I think that the problem is related to the low-pass filter state: if I fix the low-pass filter parameters, I hear no artifacts, however if i change its parameters, I hear clicking for each change in parameters.

At the moment I am saving the low-pass filter state as showed in the code above, then the output `y` is going to be convolved with the HRTF and then sent to the audio output channels.

I think I am missing some theoretical background to understand where is the problem, I know about the techniques like Overlap-Add, Overlap-save ecc... to avoid discontinuities between processed frame, but I don't really know how to "behave" when I am using a cascade of filters.

How do I correctly save the low-pass filter state to avoid audible artifacts between audio frames when I change its parameters?

**EDIT: Extra infos as asked in comments:**

I am using PyAudio to process audio frames in real time. The "core" function is the following:

```
def convolve_cycle(self, audio_frame):
    '''
    Processing each track of the frame using the scipy overlap and add convolution, but also performing overlap and on the whole
    thing since we are processing the input by frames. audio_frame is supposed to contain multiple audio tracks, which will be spatially rendered. At the moment I am testing with a single audio track
    '''
    # Setting up output arrays.
    audio_left = np.zeros((self.tracks_num, self.frame_count + self.M_left - 1), dtype=self.input_array.dtype)
    audio_right = np.zeros((self.tracks_num, self.frame_count + self.M_right - 1), dtype=self.input_array.dtype)

    #Applying the low-pass filter. 
    for i in range(audio_frame.shape[0]):
        audio_frame[i]=self.bandPassFilter(audio_frame[i], self.highcut)

    for i in range(audio_frame.shape[0]):
        #print('printing leftover',self.leftover_left[i])
        try:
            audio_left[i] = ss.oaconvolve(audio_frame[i], self.IR_left[i], mode='full') + self.leftover_left[i] #Qui aggiunge i leftover precedenti
            audio_right[i] = ss.oaconvolve(audio_frame[i], self.IR_right[i], mode='full') + self.leftover_right[i] #aggiunge leftover precedenti
        except ValueError:
            print('error')
            print(audio_frame[i].shape)
            print(self.IR_left[i].shape)

    # Saving last self.M - 1 elements for next cycle.
    self.leftover_left = np.hstack((audio_left[:, self.frame_count:],
                                    np.zeros((self.tracks_num, self.frame_count), dtype=self.input_array.dtype)))
    self.leftover_right = np.hstack((audio_right[:, self.frame_count:],
                                     np.zeros((self.tracks_num, self.frame_count), dtype=self.input_array.dtype)))

    # Discarding last self.M - 1 elements.
    audio_left = audio_left[:, :self.frame_count]
    audio_right = audio_right[:, :self.frame_count]

    return (audio_left, audio_right)
```

The above code takes an input audio frame, applies the low-pass filter (the code is available in the first part of my question), and then the output of the filter is given as input to a set of HRTF to perform spatial simulation, finally the audio is sent to the stereo output. In the process I have implemented an OLA process to avoid audio artifacts when changing the HRTF filter between frames.

The update of the lowpass filter is a simple support function that changes the value of `self.highcut`:

```
def update_cutoff(self, highcut):
    self.highcut = highcut
```

This function is called from an external thread (PyAudio generates a thread to process audio frames), this is an example:

```
count = 0
angle = 0
elevation = 0
cutoff = 100
while conv.processing():
    if angle<360:
        angle = angle+2
        cutoff = cutoff+50
    else:
        angle = 0
        elevation = elevation + 10

    required_IR = HRIRInterpreter.get_interpolated_IR(angle, elevation, 1)
    conv.update_cutoff(cutoff)
    conv.compute_IR(required_IR[1], required_IR[0])


    time.sleep(0.5)
```

where `HRIR_interpreter` is a class that manages the HRTF database and returns the interpolated impulse response for a desired position, while the `conv` object is an instance of the `Convolutioner` class which is responsible for the audio processing. The `Convolutioner` class contains all the above methods I showed (`bandPassFilter`, `convolve_cycle` and `update_cutoff`).

I tried to keep it as minimal as possible, due to the big amount of code I have.

Comment: Without seeing your filter processing 'engine', just be sure that filter with updated parameters does not break processing of the current one.

Comment: What do you mean with "break processing of the current one"?

Comment: Depends on your filter processing block so, can you show source code of processing of the LPF (including coefficient calculation routine and info of the mechanism how processing block gets the new coefficients after parameter change).

Comment: What additional process did you do when you change the filter parameters? Did you use the previous filter states for a new lowpass filter?

Comment: I updated the question with some more details. @ZRHan I am using the previous saved states for the new low pass filter. I am savid the state inside ```self.filter_state``` and then I use it in the new low pass filter

Comment: This is definitely wrong. If the filter doesn't change, using the saved states is right. For time-variant filters, I'll apply an overlap-add, one part is input signal filtered by previous LPF with saved states, another part is input signal filtered by current LPF with zero states.

Comment: If you set the LPF cut-off manually (in one step) lets say from 1000Hz to 2000Hz, does it click then?

Comment: @JuhaP I tested it by adding a "switch" to the cut-off frequency after 10 seconds (from 20000 hz (no cut basically) to 500Hz), and in the right moment of the switch I can hear a really big clicking, then it disappear (it happens only when i change the low pass parameters)

Comment: If needed, I can upload an audio demo of the problem

Comment: Is the click there if you change cut-off from lets say 1000Hz to 1001Hz? Actually, putting coefficient calculation into processing loop (as you have done in bandPassFilter()) is not very good choice and also may cause artifacts in real time applications. When you change the cut-off frequency, do you see spike in CPU performance meter? If you disable HRTF filtering do you get same artifacts?

Comment: I made the tests: 1) Changing from 1000Hz to 1001Hz still introduces a small artifact (however I noticed that such clicking is present for every frame), bigger jumps in the frequency cut-off lead to bigger clicks. The time varying filter alone works fine, the HRTF alone works fine, but combined together into a cascade, I keep getting these clicking at the beginning of every processed audio frame

Comment: If needed I can provide some audio demos. I think that the problem is the "interface" between the low-pass filter (which in this case is an IIR butter) and the HRTF (which are FIR). If taken alone (low pass and HRTF separately), they work fine. I am able to perform frame processing with changing parameters by saving the filter state (in the case of the low pass) and changing the HRTF by using overlap add to avoid clicks. When I combine them together (cascade of low pass + HRTF) i get clicks. I can't figure out where is the problem, it is for sure something related to "carry on" the samples

Comment: Did you try process LPF inside the same loop as HRTF ... or process LPF as a last step before output ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the first option, but it doesn't change anything. I discarded the second option because this is going to use 2 low-pass filters instead of one, and it's more computationally expensive. Since the low-pass filtering between the two stereo outputs is identical, I thought it was reasonable to filter before applying the HRTF, thus saving computation resources using only a single low-pass filter instead of two